# while true: check if name in names

Tags: python

```
amount_of_names = int(input("Input amount of players: "))
names = []

for counter in range(amount_of_names):
  name = str(input("Input players first name: "))
  names.append(name)
#print (names)
selected_name = str(input("Input your name: "))
import random 
names = random.choice(names)
while True:
  name in names 
  import random 
  names = random.choice(names)
  break
print (names)
```

I would like the "while true" statement to run until "name" and "names" do not match, if the name does not match, then print the non-matching name. Atm I only get a letter as an output or a syntax error whilst trying to get this working,   effectively unable to be matched with their name if it is already in the list - if anyone can help it would be much appreciated

```
amount_of_names = int(input("Input amount of players: "))
names = []

for counter in range(amount_of_names):
    name = str(input("Input players first name: "))
    names.append(name)
#print (names)
selected_name = str(input("Input your name: "))
import random 
names2 = random.choice(names)
while True:
    if name != names2:
        import random 
        names2 = random.choice(names)
        print (name, names2)
        break
    else: names2 = random.choice(names)

Input amount of players: 6
Input players first name: aa
Input players first name: ss
Input players first name: dd
Input players first name: ff
Input players first name: gg
Input players first name: hh
Input your name: ss
hh hh
```

Comment: Have you tried using any kind of `if` statement?

Comment: You could do `if name == names: break`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes ... but I couldn't manage to get it working

Comment: Could you show what you tried?

Comment: @Eric would that work with just one name, wouldn't it need all of the names present ?

Comment: @Eric see edited version with if statement above

Comment: I think I'm not understanding your end goal entirely, but yes you're right my original suggestion won't work sorry abt that... do you think you could elaborate on what you would like to happen, like where 'name' is coming from in your while statement for example?

Comment: @Eric, in essence, i want this section of the program to collect names of individuals and a name of a user and then  matching the user's name with another (but not their own) as a randomised output, what I have so far is just trying to repeatedly loop until you get two different names, which I cannot get to work. Also, this may leave you slightly out of context at the overall end goal if you feel it would help to have full context I can happily give you the question

Comment: What I would do, if I'm understanding correctly is to first give the variable in `names = random.choice(names)` a different name (this is essentially why you were returning random letters not entire names, in short). so lets just go with `names2 = random.choice(names)`... then I would set my if statement to check if the random name from the list is NOT equal to the username, and print both names, `if name != names2: print (name,names2) break`... then add an else statement to select a new random name if the username and the name do match, `else: names2 = random.choice(names)`.

Comment: @Eric some strange behaviour is going on, which probably is down to my own mistake, but could you look at the code above again I will include the results I got from this.

Comment: I'll post my code as an answer so you can see the differences, it's hard for me to show clearly in a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
amount_of_names = int(input("Input amount of players: "))
names = []

for counter in range(amount_of_names):
  name = str(input("Input players first name: "))
  names.append(name)
#print (names)
selected_name = str(input("Input your name: "))
import random 
names2 = random.choice(names)
while True:
    if name != names2:
        print (name,names2)
        break
    else:
        names2 = random.choice(names)
```